Migrate to Inno Setup from InstallAware/MSI
I have had InstallAware 12 for ages as part of Embarcadero product years ago.
This is no longer available from Embarcadero downloads, and InstallAware is very expensive for a hobby developer. Hence, I want to migrate my existing InstallAware projects to Inno Setup.
I have worked out how to setup an installer and place my files where I want.
Ideally, I would like to have the Inno Setup installer replace my existing app instead of making another install so that I can send people update for my application and it will replace previous installation.
InstallAware has a "product code" and a "Revision code" for the installation.
Is it possible to use these in Inno Setup so the installer identifies my application as the same one installed by InstallAware.
If so, how do I do this?
I tried setting the Inno Setup "AppId" to the "Product Code" but that doesn't seem to work, I wind up with a new app in windows.

Inno Setup cannot use other installations. You have to code it. The easiest would be to make it uninstall the Installaware installation and install its own afresh. You will find many questions about this here (not Installaware  specific).

You are free to uninstall any MSI package (produced from InstallAware or something else) you want in InitializeSetup.
[Code]
const
  INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT = 5;
  ProductCode = '{34144E9F-E889-467D-A28C-3858D9EBAE24}'; // PHP Manager 2 for IIS is used here. Replace with the actual MSI Product Code

function MsiQueryProductState(ProductCode: String): Integer;
  external 'MsiQueryProductStateW@msi.dll stdcall';

function IsMSIInstalled(ProductCode: String): Boolean;
var
  State: Integer;
begin
  State := MsiQueryProductState(ProductCode);
  if State = INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT then
    Result := True
  else
    Result := False;
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  UserResponse: Integer;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if IsMSIInstalled(ProductCode) then
  begin
    UserResponse := MsgBox('An existing installation of this MSI package was detected. Do you want to uninstall it before proceeding?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO);
    if UserResponse = IDYES then
    begin
      if Exec('msiexec.exe', '/x ' + ProductCode + ' /quiet /norestart', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
      begin
        if ResultCode = 0 then
          MsgBox('MSI uninstalled successfully.', mbInformation, MB_OK)
        else
          MsgBox('MSI uninstallation failed with error code: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbError, MB_OK);
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      MsgBox('Proceeding with installation without uninstalling the existing MSI package.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    MsgBox('Didn''t find an existing installation', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;

  Result := True;
end;

Note that the code is just for demonstration purposes. You have to revise it further to meet your exact requirements.

But not from InitializeSetup. That occurs even before user confirms the installation. You should use CurStepChanged(ssInstall).

Ok, but you claim "detection", without actually doing any :)

Thanks for the response.  This detects the current installation and attempts to uninstall but generates an error "MSI uninstallation failed with error code: 1603".  I tried the same code in CurStepChanged and it never detected the other installation.

Actually I commented too soon. The CurStepChanged also detects the installation but gives same error code. I didn't realise that doing the check on this step means I go through most of the installation questions before being prompted to remove the previous installation.

@BarryAndrews msiexec.exe /x {GUID} is the common way to uninstall an MSI package. If you hit the well known 1603 error code, that's a separate issue with this specific MSI package, and you need to analyze further (often by enabling diagnostics logging). I won't be able to help much on that.

It seems the msiexec refers to the temporary location used during the install, rather than the actual location of the msi file for the uninstall.  Running from add/remove programs correctly uninstalls the application, so it is able to find the original msi. Strange that the two look in different locations, I may have to just advise that the old installaware version needs to be manually removed first, not ideal but at least a work around.

@BarryAndrews Have a look at the HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall sub key of the old version to find out the exact command (UninstallString) that is used to uninstall the product through ARP. You may want to add the quiet and norestart switches.

Thanks to @Lex Li and @zett42 I can now uninstall the InstallAware application.
I use the code from Lex Li to determine if the original InstallAware application is installed and then I use @zett42 advice and find the uninstall string from the registry.
function MsiQueryProductState(ProductCode: String): Integer;
  external 'MsiQueryProductStateW@msi.dll stdcall';

function IsMSIInstalled(ProductCode: String): Boolean;
var
  State: Integer;
begin
  State := MsiQueryProductState(ProductCode);
  if State = INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT then
    Result := True
  else
    Result := False;
end;

  if IsMSIInstalled(ProductCode) then
  begin
    if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\' + ProductCode, 'UninstallString', UninstallString) then
      begin
        if Exec(UninstallString, '/s MODIFY=FALSE REMOVE=TRUE UNINSTALL=YES', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
        begin
          if ResultCode = 0 then
          begin
            MsgBox('MSI uninstalled successfully.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
            Result := True;
           end
          else
          begin
            MsgBox('MSI uninstallation failed with error code: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbError, MB_OK);
            Result := False;
          end;
        end;
      end;
   end;

I can find the Uninstall executable used by InstallAware by looking for the UninstallString of the HKLM for the product code.
Executing this UninstallString correctly removes the application.

Then the IsMSIInstalled check is basically redundant and your code is more or less common How to automatically uninstall previous installed version in Inno Setup? – nothing MSI specific, except for use of ProductCode instead of AppId.

If UninstallString shows a pattern for your InstallAware installer, you just need to change the Exec line from my answer (which uses a generic command). There is no need to read registry keys IMHO.

The command in the registry includes an uninstall GUID, so will not be the same for every computer, hence you do need to look it up.

On my computer the product code starts {CFFA89AC-, but the uninstall GUID starts with {D6E332EC- which means I cannot just use the product key, but rather I need to query the registry to find the GUID of the uninstall exe.  The exe is "c:\ProgramData\GUID2\application name".  This second GUID is the Installaware "Revision Code" GUID and this changes according to which build of the installer was used to install the application.

To migrate from Installaware but to keep using the Delphi IDE you can use RAD & Installer.
It is 3rd party expert for RAD Studio that works with Inno Setup Scripts (also supports NSIS).

